# Как добавить контент в MDFloatingActionButton

Tags: python, события, kivy, виджет

Начал изучать KivyMD, и увидел MDFloatingActionButton, меня это заинтересовало, и я решил воспользоватся ним. От правда понятия не имею как туда добавлять виджеты по-типу TextInput, Button, Progres Bar, или ещё лутше, открыть новое окно, которое было бы очень полезным, и в тему к программе. Помогите, буду благодарен, а если подскажете как открыть новое окно при нажатие на неё, то очень! Просто я не знаю как в KivyMD открыть новое окно: )

Вот код:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.taptargetview import MDTapTargetView

from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang import Builder
import random

Window.size = (480, 800)

KV = """
MDScreen:

    MDToolbar:
        id: toolbar
        title: "A"
        md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
        elevation: 10
        right_action_items: [['dots-vertical', lambda x: x]]
        pos_hint: {"top": 1}

    MDFloatingActionButton:
        id: button
        icon: "plus"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .92, "center_y": .05}
        on_release: app.tap_target_start()

"""


class TapTargetViewDemo(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        screen = Builder.load_string(KV)
        self.tap_target_view = MDTapTargetView(
            widget = screen.ids.button,
            title_text = "1",
            description_text = "2",
            widget_position = "right_bottom",
        )

        return screen

    def tap_target_start(self):
        if self.tap_target_view.state == "close":
            self.tap_target_view.start()
        else:
            self.tap_target_view.stop()


TapTargetViewDemo().run()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MDFloatingActionButton](https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/components/button/index.html#mdfloatingactionbutton) - это кнопка! Каким образом (а, главное, зачем) вы собираетесь в кнопку (!) добавлять виджеты `по типу TextInput, Button, Progres Bar`?